# C: OR operator in return line?

Tags: c, function, return, return-value, or-operator

Came across some code that has an **OR** operator (`||`) in the `return` line. Could someone explain what that does ?

---

Here's something that looks like it:

```
int main()
{
    ...

    return (1 || 0);
}
```

But really it was a function *(that returned 1 or 0)* instead of the 1 and 0:

```
int main()
{
    ...

    return (foo(x++, y) || foo(x, y++));
}
```

Comment: `||` is an operator, like `+` or `/`. It evaluates to `0` or `1`.

Comment: As in .. if its not 1 .. then we return 0 ?

Comment: return with OR as input 1 is always 1. In that case having a `return (1 || 0)` you can just write as `return 1`. In C non zero return value is widely used and considered as false.

Comment: You can just print it and check what's the value of `0||1` which is nothing unusual from the logical `OR` operation & that value is being returned

Comment: Are you wondering what the operator does, or are you surprised that it's used for computing a return value? (The return value can be any expression that has the correct type.)

Comment: That's some horrible code. Pondering what it does isn't very meaningful. The real question you should ask is: "why did this clown programmer not write something like `result = foo(x, y); if(result) return 1; x++; return foo(x, y) != 0;` instead?" Especially ask yourself: "what where they smoking when they wrote `return something++;`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a || b` evaluates to 1 if `a` is non-zero irrespective of the value of `b`, evaluates to 1 if `a` is 0 and `b` is non-zero, else it's 0.

So `1 || 0` is `1`, as would be `2 || 0`.

Note that `b` is **not** evaluated if `a` is non-zero: so if `b` was a function, it would not be called in such a case. So in your example, `foo(x, y++)` is **not** called **including** the evaluation of `y++` if `foo(x++, y)` is non-zero.

Note that the type of `a || b` is an `int` irrespective of the type of the arguments. Cf. C++ where the type is a `bool`.

Comment: So it just returns what's true.. (i.e not 0) ? And hold on, if `a` is not 1 but say another non-zero value, say `19` or `-70`, why doesn't it return that integer instead ?

Comment: @Lion: The value is either 0 or 1. I'm using `a` and `b` in a general sense.

Comment: Alright ... if any of the functions returns a non-zero value, then 1 is returned, else 0 is. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Logical OR has a [short circuit property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). The RHS is only evaluated if the LHS is evaluated to false.

In this case, since the operands are function call, so

- the LHS function call `foo(x++, y)` will be made.
- If the return value is 1 (TRUTHY), the RHS will not be evaluated and the value `1` will be returned.
- If the returned value is 0, the `foo(x,  y++)` function call with made, and the return value will be based on teh return value of the function call.